# Android: SplashScreen Image getting streched for Android 12

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to addd a splash screen i did the following steps and it worked for android 11

1. added the implementation
2. changed the compileSDKVersion to 31
3. made a layered list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_my_splash_icon">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

4. embeded the layered list in my theme

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
    </style>
```

5. changed the manifest theme to SplashTheme
6. added the installSplashScreen() to the MainActivity

this worked perfectly for Android 11 API 30
but the image is getting stretched out of proportions and is cropped inside the **icon circle** for Android 12 API 31, My icon being a rectangle shaped word design.

I read one of the answers suggesting to add the bitmap inside the items of layered list but after adding the bitmap the icon doesnt render in the design view of android studios and i only get a black screen while running the app.

```
  <item>
        <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_my_splash_icon"/>
    </item>
```

And i am not allowed to manually enter scale dimensions to make it look better.

Comment: Just use the Asset Studio to create an Adaptive Icon, it handles all dpis well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue. Using a PNG asset left me with an oversized circle cutout from my logo. What wound up working for me was to convert my logo to an SVG and add it to the project via the Vector Asset tool.

Edit: If the SVG asset is above a certain size, it becomes a circle again. That cutoff size is deceptively small.

To change the splash screen logo size, I recreated the SVG asset with padding around the icon which matched my background color. That fooled the Vector Asset tool enough to get it down to the size I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same exact issue. I had a PNG asset with an aspect ratio of 1x2 which was cropped pretty bad on `1.0.0.alpha02`. So to fix that I used `Adobe XD` to convert this PNG asset to squared 108dp to 108dp SVG file which I added to my drawable folder via Vector Asset tool as an XML file. Then I used that XML file on my SplashScreen theme at themes.xml to finally get everything working.

Also, as CodeBlue04 mentioned above you need to add some paddings to your logo, in my case the paddings were equaled to 18dp.